# Jaggy edges, dull output after rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers, node-editor, shader-nodes

[image]I did a company logo design but after rendering,

- the image was dull
- the edges of the design was too jaggy and rough.
- Light effect at the down right side of the image
- Again I like the image to have metallic sides, while the surface area retain white color.
  I like to send the .blend file so that experienced can help check the problems. I don't mind someone fixing and send back to me.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hello, Nwabuisi.. The difference is sometimes subtle, but we're not here to fix your file. We're here to answer questions for you, so you can fix problems for yourself :)  By all means share your .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ , pasting the generated link into your post, then hopefully some of us will come up with suggestions for improvement to the problems you indicate. It's hard to help with this one _without_ a share, because there are quite a few variables to take into account.

Comment: I really tried to upload a .blend file with the link, but it cant send. Please guide me

Comment: HI, there, maybe your file is too big for blend-exchange .. what size is it? Sometimes people come up  geometry that's way too dense .. If you;'re not sure, can you switch on a wire-frame view (Object > Viewport Display > [ check 'wire frame'].. and send a shot of that, so we can see?